# toJson(Map("success"->true, "message"->str)) can't be compiled in play2

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

This is my code:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Json._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes._

class BaseController extends Controller with Secured with DefaultWrites {

  private implicit def str2json(str: String) = new {
    def asSuccessJson = toJson(Map("success" -> true, "message" -> str)) // (*)
    def asFailedJson = toJson(Map("success" -> false, "message" -> str)) // (*)
  }

}
```

But it can't be compiled on two `(*)` lines. The error message is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- No Json deserializer found for type scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Any]. Try 
 to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
- not enough arguments for method toJson: (implicit tjs: 
     play.api.libs.json.Writes[scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Any]])
     play.api.libs.json.JsValue.Unspecified value parameter tjs.
```

I have to write it as:

```
def asSuccessJson = toJson(Map("success" -> true.toString, "message" -> str))
```

Notice `true.toString`. It works but boring.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite logical: you try to convert an heterogeneous map into a JsValue:

`Map("success" -> true, "message" -> str)` is a `Map[String, Any]`.

There is no implicit writer able to convert a `Map[String, Any]` into a `JsValue` (and there can't be any).

When you write `Map("success" -> true.toString, "message" -> str)`, you create a Map[String, String] and there is a writer for this.

I would write:

```
def asSuccessJson = JsObject(Seq("success" -> JsBoolean(true), "message" -> JsString(str))) // (*)
```

BTW, the JSON [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) will certainly be "beautified" a bit in Play 2's next releases...

Comment: Wait for the next release, current one is not perfect.

Comment: current api is a bit raw but it brings everything we need without any magic, any introspection. Those principles will be kept with some sugar and some new tools... be patient ;)

Comment: In theory would it be possible to write a serializer that on runtime tries to serialize all values of Map[String, Any] with existing serializers? It's not possible to write format agnostic API layer without capability to serialize on runtime the Any if possible